# Bundling CSS files in VS2012 Express Web

Tags: css, web, visual-studio-2012, bundling-and-minification

Mine is a peculiar situation. May be not. I have a solution in VS2012 Web Express. Not ASP.NET, not MVC. Just a solution full of static html files. I recently added a bunch (say 20 some) CSS files. I need to use some kind of bundling. Web Essentials doesn't work on express editions.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this for Sharepoint?

Comment: No, it is not, @adaam. It is plain and simple website with html files in it.

Comment: Just do it manually (CSS: http://cssminifier.com/ HTML: http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/)